# Trim figure (Matplotlib, 3D)

Tags: python, matplotlib

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig, auto_add_to_figure=False)
fig.add_axes(ax)
ax.plot([0, 1], [1, 0], [-1, 1])
```

yields (borders added manually)

[image]

Adding

```py
for anm in ('x', 'y', 'z'):
    getattr(ax, f'set_{anm}ticks')([])
    getattr(ax, f'w_{anm}axis').set_pane_color((1, 1, 1, 0))
    getattr(ax, f'w_{anm}axis').line.set_color((1, 1, 1, 0))
    getattr(ax, f'set_{anm}margin')(0)
```

I get what's on left, but I seek what's on right

[image]

How can this be accomplished? [Full code](https://replit.com/@OverLordGoldDra/BountifulWrathfulMicroscope#main.py)

I seek a *native* solution (no save-stage post-processing, or third party libraries), as the figure is processed further natively in matplotlib (specifically in an animation). Ideally the solution is general-purpose, i.e. not specific to `Axes3D`.

To test the answer, it should produce the following output in [full context code](https://replit.com/@OverLordGoldDra/YouthfulQuickwittedActionscript#main.py), as a .mp4 (I got this output with manual post-processing):

[image]

Comment: consider adding some zoom via Axes3D.set_box_aspect. I don't know how to make the zoom automatically though.

Comment: @LudvigH This appears to only change aspect _ratios_, and `zoom` changes figure size.

Comment: ok sorry. I thought the zoom would change figure size in the desired way.